# Firing jQuery code before page loads, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery which currently runs when the oducment is ready but what it is doing is resizing the height of an element but looks ugly as it changes the height once page is loaded so my question is: is it possible to load the code and set the height before its displayed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set hero height to max viewport
    var heroHeight = $(window).height();
    var smsHeight = $('#send-text').height();
    $('#oasis-hero').css('min-height', heroHeight - smsHeight - 140 + 'px');

    // hide video
    $('#hero-video').hide();

    // click function to auto play video
    $('.hero-text .primaryCta').on('click touchend', function (e) {
        $("#hero-video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        $('#hero-video').show();
        $('#hero-video-bg').hide();
        $('.hero-text').hide();

        $(this).unbind("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `$(window).load()` instead

Comment: @JustinIurman Bad idea, that will be executed even later than `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Should have read more carefully

Comment: Yea i tried that and as Teemu said, actions later.

Comment: @JamesBrandon Can't you just set the size with CSS? There's [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function available in most of browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely possible. You just need yo place your code AFTER the relevant html elements definition. You just need to avoid referencing elements that are not yet created.

For instance, this code would perfectly work outside document ready event

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
    $('#myDiv').hide(); // <-- will hide 'myDiv' since the element is already created
</script>
```

While this code would do nothing

```
<script>
    $('#myDiv').hide(); // <-- won't hide 'myDiv' since the element is not created yet
</script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I would but we have realy strict methods here and has to be within the 1 JS file as its all minified and cannot do JS in the pages.

Comment: @James Brandon: that's not a limitation. You can write the necessary code in that single js file outside the document ready handler. Be sure to put the js reference at the end of the page what is a good practice in any case.

Comment: I did place it outside of the document ready but did not seem to fire and yes i agree JS should be laoded at the bottom however they dont do it here but i will raise and see if we can change.

Comment: @James Brandon: without referencing the js file after the html definition this won't work. You really should be loading your js files as late as possible to improve site performance in general. (js files loading blocks UI rendering)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is the height of the window which will be calculated accurately once whole DOM is loaded .

```
var heroHeight = $(window).height();
```

I like the idea where you first hide the element whose height you want to adjust and  then finally show with an animation using  say ***fadein***.